# Why my 2-D character moves up, even though I did not even pressed keys?

Tags: java, 2d, game-development

I was learning how to make 2-D games for self-development by reference to the [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpH33Uw-_0E&list=PL_QPQmz5C6WUF-pOQDsbsKbaBZqXj4qSq&index=2]

So at the below, you will see three simple class codes. I checked every line but still, when I run the game, white rectangle directly starts to move up. Any help is great kindness.

### Main Class

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("MY 2-D GAME");
        
        GamePanel gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        window.add(gamePanel);
        
        window.pack();
        
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        
        gamePanel.startGameThread();
    }

}
```

### GamePanel Class

```
package main;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    private static final int FPS = 60;
    final int originalTileSize = 16;
    final int scale = 3; 
    
    final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale; // 48x48
    final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol;
    final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;
    
    KeyHandler key_Handler = new KeyHandler();
    
    Thread gameThread;
    
    int player_x = 100;
    int player_y = 100;
    int player_speed = 4;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth,screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(key_Handler);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        
        
    }

    
    public void startGameThread() {
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    
    public void run() {
        
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/FPS;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        
        long current_time;
            
        while (gameThread != null) {
            current_time = System.nanoTime();
            
            delta += (current_time - lastTime) / drawInterval;
            
            lastTime = current_time;
            
            if (delta >= 1) {
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
    public void update() {
        if (key_Handler.upMove = true) {
            player_y -= player_speed;
        }
        
        else if (key_Handler.downMove = true) {
            player_y += player_speed;
        }
        
        else if (key_Handler.leftMove = true) {
            player_x -= player_speed;
        }
        
        else if (key_Handler.rightMove = true) {
            player_x += player_speed;
        }
        
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(player_x,player_y, tileSize, tileSize);
        g2.dispose();
        
        
         
    }
}
```

### KeyHandler Class

```
package main;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;



public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener{
    
    public boolean upMove, downMove, leftMove, rightMove;
    
    
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upMove = true;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            downMove = true;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            leftMove = true;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            rightMove = true;
        }
        
        
    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upMove = false;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            downMove = false;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            leftMove = false;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            rightMove = false;
        }
        
    }



}
```

Comment: `if(key_Handler.upMove = true)` is using the assignment operator `=`. So you are setting the value to true and then use that as a condition. Comparing is done via the `==` operator and for boolean values not even necessary. Change it to just `if(key_Handler.upMove)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick skim, I think I found the culprit:

```
if (key_Handler.upMove = true) {
    player_y -= player_speed;
}
```

Remember that for comparisons in C-style languages, you need double equals (==), or better yet, just put `key_handler.upMove` in the parenthesis alone because it is already a boolean. So change your if statements to look like the following:

```
if (key_Handler.upMove) { // or key_Handler.upMove == true if you prefer.
    player_y -= player_speed;
}
```

Your code was assigning `key_handler.upMove` to true and using that in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using:

```
if (key_Handler.upMove = true) {
    player_y -= player_speed;
}
```

Use:

```
if (key_Handler.upMove) {
    player_y -= player_speed;
}
```

And the same for other conditions as well.